# Dynamically adding tabs in react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating an app in which the user selects certain regions from dropdown and i want to create tabs for each selected region dynamically.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by tabs? elements in tab bar?

Comment: I am building an app where the user selects multiple regions from picker and according to the number of regions the tabs should be created on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I end up using `react-native-tab-view` and managed to implement dynamic tab navigation.

On our app we have group permissions so if the user is an admin on group he can see the megaphone the first tab and if he is not an admin he can't see.

[group side navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI3nb.png)

[Tab navigation if the user is admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7sXX.png)

[Tab navigation if the user is not an admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7cie.png)